# Why isn't console.log working in the following Express code?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm using PouchDB and Express to fetch documents from a database:

**server.js:**

```
var express = require('express')
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb')

var app = express()
var db = new PouchDB('vuedb')

// handle PouchDB stuff

app.get('/docs', function(req, res) {
  function map (doc, emit) {
    if (doc.type === 'project') {
      emit(doc.createdAt)
    }
  }
  db.query(map, {include_docs: true}).then(function (projects) {
    // _.map(projects.rows, (project) => (project.doc))
    console.log('PROJECTS', projects)
  })
  // res.send()
})
```

**client.js:**

```
submit () {
  this.$http.get('http://localhost:8080/docs').then(response => {
    // console.log(response) does log the response, so this submit() action is working
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

I want to confirm whether the `projects` are being fetched. But `console.log('PROJECTS', projects)` doesn't log anything in the terminal. Why is this? Is there a especial way of logging stuff in Express?

Comment: the method is same alex to log anything on the console. Nothing is printed on console pertaining to same?

Comment: console.log should work the same no matter what modules are you using. The reason your projects are not displayed is simply because your code never executes the console.log. Your DB query must be failing.
Try this:

  `db.query(map, {include_docs: true}).then(function (projects) {
    console.log('PROJECTS', projects)
  }).catch(function(error){console.log(error)})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not that. The thing is, it probably reaches an error state before. Try to catch that error

```
  db.query(map, {include_docs: true}).then(function (projects) {
    // _.map(projects.rows, (project) => (project.doc))
    console.log('PROJECTS', projects)
  }).catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  })
```

Comment: Hey, you were right. I get this error:

`[Error: Error: /home/alex/node/project/node_modules/leveldown/build/Release/leveldown.node: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32: unable to import leveldown]`

Comment: Yes, promises make code mode elegant but it's tricky to get a hang of them.